# WSO2 ApiManager Routing Database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a requirement with ApiManager DataService, I need to same request and same response but connect to different database based on a request attribute named year.
Is it possible? or I have to create a dataservice by year?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally change the `Datasource` based on a parameter.

If you want to use the same Dtaservice, you can have different contexts for the two requests like below. But still, you will have to add new query and the Datasource config.

```
<WSO2_URL>/Dataservice/getSomething/year1

<WSO2_URL>/Dataservice/getSomething/year2
```